# All kube-system pods keep crashing, etcd receives sigterm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, etcd, containerd

I'm trying to set up an on-premises Kubernetes cluster. For starters I used kubeadm to initialize my control plane on one node. But all kube-system pods constantly crash. I took a deep look into the pod logs via crictl and it turns out that most pods crash because they cannot reach the kube-apiserver on `<node IP>:6443`. And the kube-apiserver seems to crash, because it cannot reach etcd on `127.0.0.1: 2379`. And etcd 'crashes' because it receives a sigterm after a couple of minutes without any apparent reason. Using strace on the etcd container process gives:

```
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=0, si_uid=0} ---
```

I've tried flanneld, calico and weave net as CNI, without success. Swap was already disabled from the beginning. Firewall does not have any custom rules. As a kubernetes newbie I cannot think of other possible reasons why this fails and would be grateful for any hints.

System information:

- Debian 11 on VM, 2 CPUs, 8GB Memory
- Kubernetes v1.25.0
- kubeadm, kubectl, kubelet version: 1.25.0-00, all installed via apt following [kubeadm installation docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)
- containerd v1.6.8, installed following [getting-started guide](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md) using binary from releases

  - runc v1.1.4 binary from [GitHub](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/releases)
  - containernetworking plugins v1.1.1 from [GitHub](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases)
- Cgroup systemd, configured as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/#configuring-the-kubelet-cgroup-driver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having the same issue with etcd. Are you by any chance using `--upload-certs` and have a multi-master environment?

Try adding:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

To your `/etc/default/grub` file and then run `update-grub`, reboot and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now everything is running smoothly, and I would never have found this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after installing an HA cluster on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS , although following the same exact steps to configure cgroup on kubernetes and containerd , the newly joined nodes pods were continuosly crashing until i followed the recommendations on slyke